# Input fields as lists in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to take inputs from the user and append them to a list I have in my typescript. Here's what I have tried so far.

Here's the code:

```html
<input type="text"  id="course" name="course"  class="form-control"[(ngModel)]="institutes.course">
```

```js
institutes={course:''}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a function to add a new course and trigger it using a button.

**app.component.html** :

```
<!-- Input field -->
<input type="text" id="course" name="course" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="newCourse">
<!-- Add button -->
<button (click)="addCourse()">Add</button>
```

**app.component.ts** :

```
newCourse : string = '';
allCourses : string[] = [];

// Function to add course
addCourse(){
    this.allCourses.push(this.newCourse);
    //Reset input
    this.newCourse = '';
}
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzh42b

Comment: Or you could trigger by hitting enter, but this is the correct basic approach.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will help you to add a course into a list, which will be displayed in the web page.

**.ts**

*`courseList` contains a list of all the added courses*

*`course` is the current course that you are adding.*

*`addCourse` is a method which will add a course into the list, and clear the `course` string.*

```js
public courseList = [];
public course;

addCourse() {
  this.courseList.push(this.course);
  console.log(this.courseList);
  this.course = '';
}
```

**.html**

*There is an `input` field which will take in course name.*

*And an add course `button` which will add the entered course name into the list and display the course list in the web page.*

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let course of courseList">
    {{course}}
  </li>
</ul>
<input type="text" id="course" name="course"  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="course">
<button (click)="addCourse()">Add Course</button>
```

Comment: In this case, you need to create something like a form, which will take all the fields as input, inside of `addCourse`, you need to create a new class of this type and push it into the array of `courseList` and while displaying, use `{{course.name}}` in the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

```js
Write the following method in your component - 


constructor(private url: string, private http: HttpClient) {}

posts: any;

createPost(input: HTMLInputElement) {
    const post = { title: input.value };
    this.posts.splice(0, 0, post);
    input.value = "";
    this.service.create(post).subscribe(
      newPost => {
        post.id = newPost;
      },
      (error: AppError) => {
        this.posts.splice(0, 1);

        if (error instanceof BadInput) {
          //  this.form.setErrors(error.originalError);
        } else {
          throw error;
        }
      }
    );
  }
  
  
  
Include this method in your service - 

constructor(private url: string, private http: HttpClient) {}

create(resource) {
    return this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(resource)).pipe(
      map(response => response),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

```html
write the following code in your HTML - 


<input
  (keyup.enter)="createPost(title)"
  #title
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
/>


You are good to go now!
```